# Compounding estimator confidence with sample confidence

Tags: confidence-interval, sampling, unbiased-estimator

**tl;dr:** Given a population, we want to sample a characteristic $s$ to estimate $\mu_s$ and $\sigma_s$, in order to characterize the 90% range of $s$ on the population.  However, given a sample member *i* we can only estimate the value of $s_i$.  I.e., we can only get a confidence interval like $\widehat{s_i} \in [s_{iL}, s_{iU}]$.  Given a number of such sample estimates of *s*, how can we characterize the 90% range of *s* on the population?

If we have a production lot of "widgets," produced from identical materials via identical manufacturing processes, we typically assume that any variation in their characteristics are normally distributed.  We can then assess the lot's quality by measuring a characteristic on a small number of samples, and based on that we can determine a sample mean and a confidence interval on that mean (based on the standard error).

Suppose I have a production lot of guns, and I want to characterize the accuracy of guns in that lot by measuring a small number of sample guns.

I am using the Rayleigh distribution to characterize the accuracy of a gun.  The accuracy is sampled by shooting the gun and measuring the sample radii of the impacts on a target.  There is a [closed-form unbiased estimator](http://ballistipedia.com/index.php?title=Closed_Form_Precision#Rayleigh_Estimates) for the distribution parameter $\sigma^2$:

$$\widehat{\sigma^2} = \frac{\sum r_i^2}{2(n-1)}$$

as well as a closed-form expression for the confidence interval of the estimate:

$$\widehat{\sigma^2} \in \left[ \frac{\sum r^2}{\chi_2^2}, \ \frac{\sum r^2}{\chi_1^2} \right]$$

So I will take some number of sample guns, $n_G$, and test their accuracy to get a sample estimate $\widehat{\sigma_i^2}$ and confidence interval $[\widehat{\sigma_{iL}^2},\widehat{\sigma_{iU}^2}]$ for each.  **How can I use these samples to compute and characterize the confidence interval of *the lot's* accuracy parameter?**

The population distribution of $\sigma^2$ is *not* symmetric, since it is bounded at 0.  But for typical values and intra-lot variations one could assert that it is symmetric.

Since getting a good accuracy estimate for a single gun is non-trivial, the number of production samples that can be tested will necessarily be small (i.e., single-digits).  Nevertheless, if it is not obvious how to produce an answer in the general case, I'd be interested in seeing the solution assuming the number of samples is sufficiently normal.  I.e., **what is the confidence interval of the sampling distribution of the mean when each sampled value has a confidence interval of its own?**

Comment: When you combine the observations from a single gun, you are assuming there is a single underlying accuracy for the gun for which you can compute an estimate and a confidence interval. You have observations from several guns. Is there a single underlying accuracy they all share? If so, you may treat them as if they came from a single gun. If not, then how do you imagine the different accuracies are related?

Comment: @mef: I just added an introduction to explain that.  I am asserting that "accuracy" is a production characteristic.  So ideally it has zero variation between production samples, but in practice each "widget" has normal variation (and the variance is a function of production quality control).

Comment: Suppose you have observations for a single widget and you divide them up into a number of batches and you compute a confidence interval for each batch. Now you can throw those confidence intervals away and compute the confidence interval using all the observations, since by assumption there is a single underlying accuracy to be estimated.

Comment: @mef - That makes sense on one level.  But it fails to account for the population sample size and variation.  I.e., it doesn't address the "quality control" problem.  For example, if I only measure *s* for one widget I really can't say anything about the variance of *s* across the population.  But if I measure *s*, even coarsely, across a large number of widgets, I get *some* information about how widely *s* can vary across the population, which is the essence of the question I want to answer.

Comment: So each widget has its own (unobserved) accuracy and each "production process" produces a distribution of (unobserved) accuracies. And the goal is to estimate that distribution of (unobserved) accuracies. Is that it?

Comment: @mef: Yes!  Although, generally speaking, I'm looking for *whatever statistically rigorous and efficient statements* can be made about the value of "individual widget accuracy" across a lot of widgets, given that we can only estimate an individual widget's "accuracy," and that we can only sample a small number of widgets from a production lot.